# Virtualhosts(apache2) and DNS

Tags: apache, dns

the problem is :
I have a server (where I configured apache, dns, dhcp, ssl, mysql) that will allow me to host websites via a website interface that I created (the website is called "les-tatates.cm "and it turns on port 80 and 443, I set it to 443).

For the test case, I hosted a website called "test3", it runs on port 50002 (without ssl) and 50502 (with ssl), I set it to 50502.

I well configured the DNS because when I type in the browser search bar: https://127.0.0.1:443 apache returns my website.

https://les-tatates.cm apache returns me once again my website.

https://127.0.0.1:50502 apache returns me the website "test3"

but when I type https://test3.fr, I have this error:

```
Hum, nous ne parvenons pas à trouver ce site.

Impossible de se connecter au serveur à l’adresse test3.fr.
Si l’adresse est correcte, voici trois autres choses que vous pouvez essayer de faire :

    Réessayer ultérieurement.
    Vérifier votre connexion au réseau.
    Si vous êtes connecté au travers d’un pare-feu, vérifier que Firefox a la permission d’accéder au Web.
```

This is the virtualhost that manages the the website "test3":

```
<VirtualHost *:50002>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/test3"
    ServerName test3.fr
    ServerAlias www.test3.fr
    Redirect permanent / https://test3.fr/

    <Directory "/var/www/test3">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all 
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.test3.fr.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.test3.fr.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:50502>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/test3"
    ServerName test3.fr
    ServerAlias www.test3.fr 

    <Directory "/var/www/test3">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all 
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.test3.fr.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.test3.fr.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

My question is to know, how to associate a virtual host to a dns server so that "test3.fr" is accessible in the browser?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You need to add test3.fr in ServerAlias too.

```
ServerAlias www.test3.fr test3.fr
```

Comment: Can you try and see if you get correct answer with port - "https://test3.fr:50502"